# "Perfect" code, no output Android (Eclipse) Sound Board

Tags: android, eclipse, media-player

I'm trying to create a simple soundboard for my 3 year old and have run into quite a dilema, I thought I had found the best possible way to code the soundboard but have run into an issue when the button is clicked nothing happens??

The code is clean, no indication of errors so I'm at my wits end.

Your help is very much appreciated.

```
    public class Player extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

        MediaPlayer mp;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            Button Button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Button1);
            Button1.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.splashsound);
            mp.start();
            while (mp.isPlaying()){

            };

            mp.release();
        }
    };
```

Comment: did you debug it? does it execute the `onClick` method?

Comment: you are bloking main thread in `onClick` ... remove this code: `while (mp.isPlaying()){}; mp.release();` you should find better place for release MediaPlayer ... and where is `mp.prepare();` ?

Comment: Is the click being registered when you press the button?

Comment: @Selvin It is not necessary to have  `prepare()` you can play audio without `mp.prepare()` and while loop will block the UI thread. In my deleted post, it is `context` not `content` it was just a typo. His code is working perfectly when I copied and pasted them

Comment: heh it was te same context => Player class instance (in onClick `this` means Player Activity and v.getActivity() == this) ... and while (mp.isPlaying()){} code in onClick is bad it may causing ANR

Comment: @Pragnani anway you're right about mp.prepare() ... it is not necessary here

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup the AudioStream with the [setAudioStreamType()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setAudioStreamType%28int%29)

```
mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.ursoundboardtrack);
mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.USE_DEFAULT_STREAM_TYPE);
mp.prepare();
mp.start();
```

Comment: I've kept the code that I originally posted up but changed my sound file to a .wav but still no sound when button is pressed?

Comment: Check out the MediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener() method. Create a simple listener that prints the error messages to the log because there are a number of reason why audio playback could fail.

Answer (score 0):

Have you made sure that your splashsound is in a ***`.wav`*** format ?

If it is'nt then this App will never work as it needs to be in a .wav format not a .mp3 or .wma or any other type of audio format it has to be in a ***`.wav`*** format.

If your splashsound is in another audio format but ***`.wav`*** then you will have to convert it to a ***`.wav`*** and import it back into your project and delete the old one and hopefully it should work :)

Comment: I thought anything BUT a .wav

Comment: nope I'm sorry but its the wrong way round .wav is the only format you can use for MediaPlayer

Comment: as you can tell I'm very new to Android/Programming